# How would I handle a Future[User] versus a Future[Option[User]]?

Tags: scala, concurrent.futures

What is the difference in how you handle a Future[User] versus a Future[Option[User]]?

I am also confused as I kind of thought a flatMap removes Options, but is that restricted to them being in a collection?

Answer (score 1):

No, `flatMap` does not remove `Option`. This is a mistaken but common belief brought upon by the fact that there is an implicit conversion from `Option` to `Traversable` that allows you do to things like `List(Option(1)).flatMap(x => x)` (essentially `.flatten`.)

Instead, think of `flatMap` the same way you would do with something more akin to a Monad. Given some type `M[_]` and a function of type `A => M[B]` produce a `M[B]`. So, for `flatMap` to work for you in this case, you'd have to have a function of type `Option[User] => Future[B]` for some type `B`.

```
def doSomething(ouser: Option[User]): Future[Output] = { ...

val res: Future[Output] = futOptUser.flatMap(doSomething)
```

Comment: I want Option[User] as my final result.

Comment: I'm not so sure that "think of flatMap the same way you would do with something more akin to a Monad" is the right answer to a person that thought of `flatMap` as something that "removes" `Option`.

Comment: @ziggystar How would you say it? The biggest issue is that stupid implicit conversion. It really does confuse the issue on many fronts.

Comment: @coolbreeze the only way to get out of a `Future` is using `Await`. A `Future` isn't a collection. It's something that represents a value that will exist at some point in the future.

Comment: In a play app, would you pass a future down to the view page?  I mean you have to block at some point right?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to read and understand [docs](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html).

In brief, without blocking you can:

- transform result of the future (using `map`)
- combine results of several futures (using `flatMap`)
- add completion callback (using `onComplete`)

You can synchronously wait for future termination using `Await` to get unwrapped value, but this usually doesn't make much sense (as you are blocking your current thread).

Better add `onComplete` or `onSuccess` callback to your future (which will receive unwrapped future's result as parameter):

```
 val userFuture: Future[Option[User]] = Future { getUserOption() }
 userFuture.onSuccess {
    case userOpt:Option[User] => userOpt.foreach {  user =>
       println(user)  // watch out for thread-safety here!
    }    
 }
```

Comment: What do you mean watch out for thread safety here?  In a Play application how could this be a problem?

Comment: @coolbreeze Just keep in mind that Future's body and callback may be executed in different threads. Unfortunately I'm not familiar with play and hence can't tell which parts of it are potentially thread-unsafe.